# laravel three one to many relations

Tags: php, laravel

I learn and I want to create in laravel something like a kind of movie library. I have three tables:

Series, series_seasons, series_espisodes

**Series model:**

```
public function series_seasons()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\SeriesSeason','series_id');
}
```

**Seasons model:**

```
public function series_episodes()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough('App\SeriesEpisode','App\SeriesSeason','series_id','season_id');
    }

 public function series()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Series','series_id');
    }
```

(initially instead 'hasManyThrough' I had 'hasMany')

**episodes model:**

```
public function series_season()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\SeriesSeason','season_id');
}
```

**So my question is how can I get: series->series_seasons->all episodes of a specific season ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add field `season_id` in your `series_espisodes` table. Then you can retrieve all of them like this:

`$allEpisodes = Episodes::where('season_id', $seasonID);`

You can add `series_id` field as well, and then you can retrieve all of it like this:
`$allEpisodes = Episodes::where(['season_id'=> $seasonID, 'series_id => $seriesID]);`

This would be the easiest way of doing this, without making any complicated logic behind it. And you have everything in there. If you create it right, you can skip `seasons` table, because it's only a number. So you can have two tables, one for the series and one for the episodes. Simple and effective.

Comment: okay but is there any other way if I want to use only eloquent ?

Comment: You mean only with relationships? This is also Eloquent.

Comment: I mean eloquent ORM

Comment: I want fetch data without specifying season id, eg. my $series -> Series::findOrFail(idfromget), and all seasons and episodes of this series. Sorry, yes it's also eloquent ; p